# Is it possible to replace a 3phase inverter in matlab by a function

Tags: matlab, optimization, real-time, simulink

I'm working on a real-time simulation in an **Opal-RT simulator**, using **RT-LAB & MATLAB/Simulink** for an **active power filter**.

I want to run the simulation in **real time** but **overruns are occurring**, because the **model is apparently too big** and, so i have to **optimize** it, and one of the blocks that consumes a lot of computation time is **the 3 phase Inverter (based on IGBTs)**, a friend told me that it is possible to replace the block with a simple matrix (S-function or transfer function I'm not sure), he said that will reduce to computation time of the model and will help me run it on real-time.

- Is that possible ?
- Is a such philosophy exist in Matlab/Simulink ?
- If yes, can you guys recommend me some documentation that can help me ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

#### Theory

Your friend wants to say: convert 3-phase inverter to s-transfer function **model**. Now points to understand here are

1. `System Modeling` is engineering and not MATLAB, you can also model any system like *3-phase inverter* into models like *state space*, *s-transfer function*, *polynomial fit*, *neural networks* etc.
2. To fit or **approximate a system via model**, following points of precautions to be taken

   1. If system is non-linear, dis-continuous or data points are scattered normal models like state space won't work. **Choose your model wisely**
   2. You must have full range of inputs verses outputs to generate a model for your IGBT.
   3. For modeling real analog systems discrete step size needs to be vary small, so you need to balance out accuracy with model calculation time (*if its a part of loop*)

#### Action

If you know equation of transfer function of inverter, then try to fit and find coefficients. Otherwise results will be inaccurate. Neural fit provides best results but out of scope.

So **OPTIMIZE MODEL INSTEAD** as follows:

1. Try to use the built-in Fcn block whenever possible rather than S-functions. S-functions written as MATLAB files and slow. By converting the MATLAB file to a MEX-file, performance can be greatly improved. Also, whenever possible, use the built-in blocks to model the S-functions.
2. Increase step size, there is no need to calculate at very small step-size if model accuracy permits. We can set simulink calucations at steps 1e-20 or 1e-2. But yes a step size of 1e-2 will be much faster. Find step size with experimentation
3. Adjust model tolerances, lets say if system output in insignificant below 1e-2 then we should not choose a tolerance of computation as 1e-3 (*why calculate more ?*). Look for model tolerance asjustments
4. Reduce the time scale, why to compute for an hour in a single shot. This way system will try to reserve more memory and may go slow in case of disk caching. Compute for smaller cycles lets say minutes.
5. Try moving to a fast but relatively simple solver for your model and one which give faster speed. [Solver List](http://in.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/types-of-solvers.html)
6. Remove graphical elements from simulation, Plot results post simulation as graph updates are slow.